# OpenCV 3.0 camera not accessible by cvCreateCameraCapture

Tags: c++, c, opencv, windows-8, opencv3.0

using windows am trying to open my webcam using cvCreateCameraCapture (0); or cvCaptureFromCAM (0) but it just opens Video Source window with my camera in it when I press ok nothing happens it returns null and sometimes I get a black screen
though the camera works while using the C++ API VideoCapture but I need to use the C API 
installed quicktime and tried -1,1,2,......1000 instead of 0 any help :D ?

```
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//cvCapture
int main()
{
    IplImage * s;
    namedWindow("l");
    CvCapture* v = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    while (1)
    {
    if( s = cvQueryFrame(v))
    { 
        cvShowImage("l", s);
        cout << "in";
    }
        if (char c = waitKey(10) == 27) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&v);
    cvDestroyWindow("l");
    return 2;
}
```

[Here's what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozUH9.png)
when i press ok nothing happens it stays grey window
if i replace with this one it works but i need to work with the C API (cvCreateCameraCapture)

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture v(0);
    namedWindow("l");
    if (!v.isOpened())return 2;
    while (1)
    {
        Mat f;
        v.read(f);
        imshow("l", f);
        if (char c = waitKey(10) == 27) break;
    }
    cvDestroyWindow("l");
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: is that good or more details ?

Comment: what is your OpenCV version?

Comment: opencv 3.0 it is tagged

Comment: sorry. i also have 3.0 and same result. but i think i know the reason. wait please.

Comment: http://code.opencv.org/issues/4395

Comment: yes, you added all details needed. @sturkmen yes, I also checked that with C++ api calls DSHOW, with C api calls VFW. So it's just a missing binding to DSHOW in C api?

Comment: for more info https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2947/files

Comment: so what can i do to fix this ? sorry for your time

Comment: The short term solution seems to switch back to OpenCV 2.4.12. But probably @sturkmen is more affordable :D

Comment: can you build your dlls from source. if yes i try to suggest some solutions in short term.

Comment: please be more specific i use visual studio as u see

Comment: if i provide a change on source code of OpenCV you must to rebuild OpenCV library from source (sorry for poor english)

Answer (score 1):

it is a [known issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4395)

i personally solved the problem by merging [deleted part](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2947/files) again and build dlls.

here [cap.cpp](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/blob/master/cap.cpp) and [cap_dshow.cpp](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/blob/master/cap_dshow.cpp)

if you rebuild OpenCV 3.0 dll'd using these files you will solve your problem. otherwise you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues) describing your problem and wait a solution from developers or use OpenCV 2.4.12

Answer (score 1):

Using IplImage and Cvfunctions are long gone in Opencv. 
You can try using older versions of opencv to use these.